# Java generics compile error involving Class<? extends T>

Tags: java, generics

This program does not compile:

```
public class xx {
    static class Class1<C> {
        void method1(C p) {
        }
    }
    static class Class2<T> extends Class1<Class<? extends T>> {
        T object;
        void method2() {
            this.method1(this.object.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
xx.java:10: method1(java.lang.Class<? extends T>) in xx.Class1<java.lang.Class<? extends T>>
cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<capture#215 of ? extends java.lang.Object>)
        this.method1(this.object.getClass());
```

Why does this happen? Why does the compiler seemingly believe that `object.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Object>` instead of `Class<? extends T>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.getClass()` is defined to return a `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `T` is the statically known type of the receiver (the object `getClass()` is called on). Take special note of the vertical bars, the [erasure operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). The erasure of a type variable is the erasure of its leftmost bound. In your case that's the implicit bound `Object`. So you get back a `Class<? extends Object>`, not a `Class<? extends T>`.

Why is that?

Imagine `T = List<Integer>`, you could suddenly do the following **without unchecked warning**:

```
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> myIntyStrings = myInts.getClass().cast(myStrings);
myIntyStrings.add(-1);
String myString = myStrings.get(0); // BANG!
```

But thankfully we do get a warning.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is no upper bound set on `T` in your code, so `? extends T` is really tantamount to `? extends Object`. Just yesterday I played with a similar example and hit this barrier. I had

```
static <T> T newInstance(T o) throws Exception {
  final Class<? extends T> c = o.getClass();
  return c.newInstance();
}
```

and it complained with the same error. Consider this: the return type of `Object.getClass()` is `Class<?>` and the compiler will want to capture the `?` into a concrete type. But instead, we would like not to capture the `?`, but to "capture the upper bound" `T` -- and there is no such thing in Java's generics.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why we get `? extends Object` but not why the compilation fails. I mean, shouldn't the compiler "know" that `object.getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends T>` since `object` has type `T`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on getClass(), the returned object has type `Class< ? extends |X| >`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the type of the instance on which the method is called.

Therefore calling getClass() on an object of type `T` returns `Class< ? extends Object >`.  We have no bound information about `T` in this API.

Usually APIs which use reflection on generic classes require that the client pass an additional argument of type `Class< T >` to the constructor or generic method in question.